# Verify Demorgan's Law Algebraically

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

If $\overline X \equiv \text { not }X$,

De Morgan's Laws are stated as:

1. $ \overline{(A + B)}=  \overline A\cdot \overline B$
2. $ \overline{(A\cdot B)} = \overline A + \overline B$

**Verify the above laws algebraically.**

I can prove this using truth tables and logic gates but algebraically, I don't know any intuitive way to prove it.

$$
\begin{array}{ |c|c| }
  \hline
   {\text{Axioms}}\\
  \hline
   \text{Property of 0} & X + 0 = X \space ;\space X\cdot0 = 0 \\
   \text{Property of 1} & X + 1 = 1 \space;\space X\cdot1 = X\\
   \text{Idempotence Law} & X + X = X \space;\space X\cdot X = X\\
   \text{Involution Law} & \overline{\overline X} = X\\
   \text{Complementarity Law} & X + \overline X = 1 \space;\space X\cdot\overline X = 0\\
   \text{Commutative Law} & X+Y = Y+X \space;\space X\cdot Y = Y\cdot X\\
   \text{Associative Law} & (X+Y)+Z = X+(Y+Z) \space;\space (X\cdot Y)\cdot Z = X\cdot (Y\cdot Z)\\
   \text{Distributive Law} & X(Y+Z) = XY + XZ \space;\space X + YZ = (X+Y)(X+Z)\\
   \text{Absorption Law} & X + XY = X \space;\space X(X+Y) = X\\
   \text{Other (3rd Distributive)} & X + \overline XY = X+Y\\
  \hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: What are the axioms?

Comment: @GitGud: What do you mean? Like the law of ones, zeroes, Idompotence law etc?

Comment: Yes. And don't forget the rules regarding $\neg$.

Comment: @GitGud: Involution and the Complementarity Laws? How do I use that to prove this?

Comment: Please list the axioms in the question and not just their names, but the actual syntactic formulation of them.

Comment: @GitGud: I'm so sorry. I thought these were generally known. I have added as many *axioms* as I know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By Complementarity Law, 
$$P + \overline P = 1 \space\text{ and }\space P \cdot \overline P = 0$$

(Note: I shall only be using $P + \overline P = 1$ as its dual is automatically true)

---

**First Law::**
DeMorgan's $1^{\text{st}}$ law states $\overline{X+Y} = \overline X \cdot \overline Y$

It is sufficient to prove that $(X + Y) +  \overline X \cdot \overline Y = 1$
$$
\begin{align}
\text{LHS} &= Y + (X + \overline X \cdot \overline Y)\\ 
&= Y +  X + \overline Y\\
&= (Y+\overline Y) + X\\
&= 1 + X \\&= 1 = \text{RHS}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Second Law::** DeMorgan's $2^{\text{nd}}$ Law states that $\overline{X\cdot Y} = \overline X + \overline Y$

It is sufficient to prove that $X\cdot Y + (\overline X + \overline Y) = 1$

$$
\begin{align}
\text{LHS} &= \overline Y + (\overline X + \overline{\overline X}\cdot Y)\\
&= \overline Y + (\overline X + Y)\\
&= (Y + \overline Y) + \overline X\\
&= 1 + \overline X\\
&= 1 = \text{RHS}
\end{align}
$$

---

Hence, DeMorgan's Laws are verified algebraically.

Comment: This is not a complete proof, since proof must be made using both of the Complementarity Law, to ensure that the proofed law (DeMorgan's Laws) is equal.  The current proof only shown like `<=`, thus not also `>=`, so `==` thus can't be inferred.  See similarity in [proof of De Morgan's laws for sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Formal_proof).

Comment: Both have to be satisfied. For example, given the boolean algebra $(P(X),\cup ,\cap )$, where $P(X)$ is the powerset of $X$. Take $A, B \in P(X)$, $A\cup B = 1$ doesn't imply $A\cap B = 0$. For example, $X = \{ 1,2,3,4,5 \}$, $A = \{ 1,2 \}$ and $B = \{ 4,5 \}$.

Comment: I am refering to both statements of the Complementarity Law.

Comment: I didn't explain myself correctly. $B=\bar{A}$ if and only if $A\cup B = 1$ **and** $A\cap B = 0$. Now, you can't use the duality principle for this last statement because these identities don't hold for any Boolean algebra, as the one I mentioned before.

Comment: Why is it sufficient to show that $X+Y+\overline{X}\cdot \overline{Y} = 1$? In boolean algebra $a+b=1$ does not necessarily imply $b=\overline{a}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Lemma:** $ A + B = 1 \land AB = 0 \implies A = \overline B $

*Proof*:

Given $ A + B = 1 $, then:

$ (A + B) \overline B = 1 \cdot \overline B = \overline B $

$\implies A \overline B + B \overline B = A \overline B + 0 = A \overline B = \overline B $   **(1)**

Given $ AB = 0 $, we combine it with **(1)** to obtain:

$ A \overline B + AB = \overline B + 0 $

$\implies A (\overline B + B) = A \cdot 1 = A = \overline B$   **QED**

**First law:**

$ (X + Y) + \overline X \overline Y = Y + (X + \overline X \overline Y) = $

$ = Y + (X + \overline Y) = (Y + \overline Y) + X = $

$ = 1 + X = 1 $   **(2)**

$ (X + Y) \cdot \overline X \overline Y = X \cdot \overline X \overline Y + Y \cdot \overline X \overline Y = $

$ = (X \overline X) \cdot \overline Y + (Y \overline Y) \cdot \overline X = 0 \cdot \overline Y + 0 \cdot \overline X = $

$ = 0 + 0 = 0 $   **(3)**

By **(2)**, **(3)**, and the lemma, we have $ \overline { X + Y } = \overline X \overline Y $ -- **QED**

**Second law:**

$ \overline { X Y } = \overline { { \overline { \overline X } } \cdot { \overline { \overline Y } } } = $   (by *First law*)

$ = \overline { \overline { \overline X + \overline Y } } = \overline X + \overline Y $   **QED**

**Notes**

- Contrary to the approach in the first answer, it is necessary to prove *both* that $ A + B = 1 $ *and* $ AB = 0 $ in order to claim that $ A = \overline B $.
- *Absorption Law* and *3rd Distributive* are redundant as axioms, following from *Property of 1*, *Complementarity Law*, *Idempotence Law*, and *Associative Law*.
- *Idempotence Law* is redundant as an axiom, following from *Property of 1* and *Distributive Law*

Comment: Alternatively, if one has already shown basic properties of the component then $(3)$ follows easily from $(2)$. In particular, if one has shown that the complement of $X$ is unique _and_ that $\overline{\overline{X}}=X$, then showing $(X+Y)+(\overline{X}\cdot \overline{Y})=1$ gives $(X\cdot Y)\cdot (\overline{X}+\overline{Y})=0$ by duality. Substituting $X$ by $\overline{X}$ and using the fact that $\overline{\overline{X}}=X$ we get $(\overline{X}\cdot \overline{Y})\cdot (X+Y)=0$.