Why does the AND take precedence over OR in most programming languages?
In many programming languages, the logical AND operator (&& or $and$) has a higher precedence than the OR operator (|| or $or$). This means that in expressions where both operators are present, the AND operations are evaluated before the OR operations unless parentheses are used to explicitly change the order of evaluation.
For example, in the expression A || B && C, the B && C part is evaluated first, and then the result is used in the OR operation with A.
I would like to understand the reasoning that led to the decision to give the AND operator precedence over OR. I believe it has to do with the OR and AND operations corresponding to addition and multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ as some algebraic structure (ring, commutative ring or semiring), because of this correspondence language designers might have mirrored how multiplication comes before addition in typical order of operations. But this correspondence is not in the logical tables:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
or & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
and & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
+ & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
* & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
but instead the structural isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and boolean logic as all operations are associative, commutative, and have an identity. AND distributes over OR as $\times$ distributes over $+$.
Is this correct? Why does the structural isomorphism between addition and multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and the logical OR and AND explain why these operations respect the same order of precedence, even though their operation tables differ?

This question is more about computer languages than about math. You might try on Retrocomputing https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ for the early programming languages. Or possibly on the Programming Language Design beta https://langdev.stackexchange.com/ but the answers there might be mostly about similarity to other languages and their histories.

While I agree with the proposed hypothesis, I am wondering whether this is the most appropriate stack. Wouldn't Programming Language Design and Implementation StackExchange be a more appropriate venue?

AND and OR have symmetry that multiplication and addition don't have; for example, OR distributes over AND just as well as AND distributes over OR. Nevertheless there is a tendency in writing mathematical logic to write AND as if it were multiplication and OR as if it were addition; for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/943164/139123. If you were to ask about that it would definitely be a math question, not programming.

Perhaps we have a bias toward disjunctive normal form.

@DavidK Well, the identity element for "and" is "true" and the identity element for "or" is "false". Isn't it more natural to think of "false" as analogous to $0$ and "true" as analogous to $1$ than the reverse?

@AlexKruckman Yes, but is AND multiplication because its identity, "true," is $1$, or is "true" $1$ because AND is multiplication? (By the way, for a good chunk of computing history, "true" was $-1$.)

From a mathematic point of view, the right structure is the Boolean semiring $\mathbb{B}$, not the field $\mathbb{F}_2$. Recall that a commutative semiring
is a set $R$ equipped with two binary operations $+$ (addition) and $\cdot$ (multiplication) satisfying the following conditions:

$(R, +)$ is a commutative monoid with identity denoted $0$,
$(R, \cdot)$ is a commutative monoid with identity denoted $1$,
multiplication distributes over addition,
$0$ is a zero for the product.

The Boolean semiring $\mathbb{B}$ is $\{0, 1\}$ equipped with the Boolean addition (or) and the Boolean multiplication (and).
Now it is a standard convention that multiplication has higher priority than addition. Moreover, as the sign $\cdot$ is often omitted, this leads to a more compact and readable mathematical notation, like $a + bc$ instead of $a + b \cdot c$ or $a + (b \cdot c)$.

Obviously there is no correct answer here, but it might have something to do with an expression in Disjunctive Normal Form being preferred over one in Conjunctive Normal Form.
